# Capture screen with fixed region

Tags: windows, macos, screen-capture

I would like to know if there is a systematical way (software) to capture a fixed region on the screen, under Windows 7 or OS X.

It must be accurate about the region. I always want to capture the region with left-top coordinate (300, 300) and right-bottome coordinate (800, 800).

So I can't not select the region by mouse myself. A software to do this capture should let me to input the 2 coordinates.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[PicPick](http://www.picpick.org/) should do this, and has some other decent options as well as good markup tools.  As a bonus, it's totally free for non-commercial use.

Comment: The added advantage of PicPick is that it is available as a portable to be carried on USB http://portableapps.com/apps/graphics_pictures/picpick-portable

Comment: @Simon - I actually never realized that, there's another point for it.

Comment: I thought it might be helpful to mention, as I totally agree PicPick is an excellent utility.

Answer (score 3):

I use [ScreenHunter](http://www.wisdom-soft.com/products/screenhunter_free.htm).  They have a free version, and an evaluation of the pro version.  I'm not sure whether your specific needs are met by the free one (I've been using pro for a while), but the pro one definitely has that feature.

Answer (score 0):

CamStudio is open source and free for personal or commercial use. It allows specifying a screen region and many other options.

http://camstudio.org/

Answer (score 0):

In terms of Apple Mac Screen Capturing Tools, SnagIt is a very powerful application (all be it not free, however does offer a free trial to test out)

http://www.techsmith.com/snagit-mac-features.html

In terms of free tools for Apple Mac, I only know that Skitch (bought out by Evernote) was a powerful tool, that may accomplish your needs:

http://evernote.com/skitch/

SnapCrab for Windows is a freeware alternative to SnagIt  which includes many of the features and none of the cost.

http://www.downloadcrew.com/article/28952-snapcrab